How to fix an error when creating a migration
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated resolveTypeReferenceDirectives signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
"typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/config/type-orm.config.ts",
"typeorm:migration:create": "npm run typeorm migration:create -- -n",  Works
"typeorm:migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n", Returns an error
"typeorm:migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run", Returns an error
